# Best way to remove spaces between digits and sum python <class 'str'>?

Tags: python, regex, task, digits

I am a learner and currently working on a task now and almost finished, but I got stuck with how finish up.
I have a < class 'str'> that looks like:

[image: Output on my terminal. Notice the spaces...]

I need to remove the spaces in-between the 2-digit numbers, so I can easily sum the whole numbers.
Below is the exact string:

```
                                                          9 7           9 7          9 0           9 0           8 8           8 7            8 7              8 0    
 7 9         7 9       7 8           7 6           7 6          7 2          7 2           6 6          6 6          6 5           6 5            6 4           6 
1            6 1          5 9          5 8           5 7         5 7                5 4          5 1          4 9          4 7         4 0          3 8           3 7 
     3 6              3 6              3 2          2 5          2 4           2 2          2 1         1 9          1 8          1 8          1 4          1 2   
       1 2            9             7           3          2
```

I have checked similar answers here with Regex, and every solution I tried seems to just either remove all the spaces(leaving one long string of digits) or separate them into single digits.

**What is the best way to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to look for a digit `'\d'` that is optionally followed by a single space and then another digit `'(?: \d)?'`. Then in a list comprehension remove the middle whitespace if there is one

```
>>> [i.replace(' ', '') for i in re.findall(r'(\d(?: \d)?)', s)]
['97', '97', '90', '90', '88', '87', '87', '80', '79', '79', '78', '76', '76', '72', '72', '66', '66', '65', '65', '64', '6', '1', '61', '59', '58', '57', '57', '54', '51', '49', '47', '40', '38', '37', '36', '36', '32', '25', '24', '22', '21', '19', '18', '18', '14', '12', '12', '9', '7', '3', '2']
```

To convert these into `int` types

```
>>> [int(i.replace(' ', '')) for i in re.findall(r'(\d(?: \d)?)', s)]
[97, 97, 90, 90, 88, 87, 87, 80, 79, 79, 78, 76, 76, 72, 72, 66, 66, 65, 65, 64, 6, 1, 61, 59, 58, 57, 57, 54, 51, 49, 47, 40, 38, 37, 36, 36, 32, 25, 24, 22, 21, 19, 18, 18, 14, 12, 12, 9, 7, 3, 2]
```

and to sum them

```
>>> sum(int(i.replace(' ', '')) for i in re.findall(r'(\d(?: \d)?)', s))
2499
```

Comment: Thank you, @CoryKramer.